# Get result of Task<T> without knowing typeof T

Tags: c#, .net, task-parallel-library

I am working on a C# system and a class has one function that returns a `System.Threading.Tasks.Task` object and has a property `System.Type` ReturnType.

When ReturnType is null i know the method return a Task object. But sadly there is no way to know if the class implementing the interface will return a `Task<ReturnType>` or `Task<object>` and i need to get the result of this method. I think the easiest way to do it would be to convert the `Task<T>` to `Task<object>` so i can get the result and handle it using the Type value in ReturnType.

How can i convert a `Task<T>` to `Task<object>` without knowing the type of T ?

```
public interface ITaskFactory
{

    ReadOnlyCollection<ParameterInfo> ParametersInfo { get; }

    Type ReturnType { get; }

    Task CreateTask (params object[] args);

}
```

I need to get the result returned by the `Task` that i received by calling `CreateTask()`

See: http://dotnetfiddle.net/Bqwz0I

Comment: Non-generic `Task` is not the same as `Task<object>`, it's a promise for `void`, it doesn't return anything.

Answer (score 6):

I have tried quite a few things and the only things that has worked for me is using reflection. I also added code that detects tasks without a value and throws an exception.

```
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Reflection;

public class Program
{
    private static async Task<object> Convert(Task task)
    {
        await task;
        var voidTaskType = typeof (Task<>).MakeGenericType(Type.GetType("System.Threading.Tasks.VoidTaskResult"));
        if (voidTaskType.IsAssignableFrom(task.GetType()))
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Task does not have a return value (" + task.GetType().ToString() + ")");
        var property = task.GetType().GetProperty("Result", BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);
        if (property == null)
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Task does not have a return value (" + task.GetType().ToString() + ")");
        return property.GetValue(task);
    }

    public static async Task Main()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Start");
        Task i = CreateTask();
        Task<object> o = Convert(i);
        Console.WriteLine("value: {0}", await o);
        Console.WriteLine("value2: {0}", await Convert(Task.FromResult<int>(123)));

        //Test for tasks without return values
        try
        {
            Console.WriteLine("value3: {0}", await Convert(Task.CompletedTask));
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("value3: EX {0}", ex.Message);
        }

        //Test for tasks without return values
        try
        {
            Console.WriteLine("value4: {0}", await Convert(Test4()));
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("value4: EX {0}", ex.Message);
        }
        Console.WriteLine("Done");
    }


    private static Task CreateTask()
    {
        return Task.FromResult("Some result");
    }

    public static async Task Test4()
    {
        await Task.CompletedTask;
        return;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

`Task<T>` [is not](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd321424%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) covariant (unlike `IEnumerable<T>`, see its [definition](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9eekhta0%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), notice the `out` [keyword](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd469487.aspx)) so you can only await it first then convert:

```
async Task<object> Do<T>(Task<T> task)
{
   // this won't compile: Cannot implicitly convert type 'Task<T>' to 'Task<object>'
   // return task;

    object result = await task;
    return result;
}
```

Comment: See this [fiddle](http://dotnetfiddle.net/sdV9LB)

Comment: I tried the code provided and when i compile i get

CommandLineInterface.cs(24,24): Error CS0411: The type arguments for method `Linsft.Software.CommandLineInterface.Convert<T>(System.Threading.Tasks.Task<T>)' cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly (CS0411) (Software)

It want me to specify the type manualy, but i can't since i don't know what type it will be....

Comment: Same error here http://dotnetfiddle.net/Bqwz0I

Comment: @madrang: That's another question of conversion between `Task` and `Task<T>`.

Comment: @madrang: this works http://dotnetfiddle.net/3gtxTJ but is different from you're looking for I guess.

Comment: Yea, because in the example you know that the type is Task<string>, thats why it works. In my case it can be anything...

Comment: `Task<T>` can't be covariant, only interfaces and delegates can.

Comment: It's not another question -- it's literally THIS question.  Read it.

Answer (score -2):

Easiest way is to use `ContinueWith`

```
    Task<T> task = null;
    Task<object> obj = task.ContinueWith(t => (object)t.Result);
```

Comment: How is this helpful if you don't have T?